# How to use T.in with gremlin-java 2.6.0

Tags: java, scala, gremlin

I am attempting to use the T.in token on a has call in Scala using the gremlin-java driver.  Ive tried passing it an, Array, List, Set, Seq and just a single string but no matter what I send I get this error,

`Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: Invalid condition: Set(typeA, typeB)]]`

Im trying to do this,
`new GremlinPipeline(g).V().has("type",T.in, Set("typeA", "typeB"))`

In straight Gremlin, `g.V().has("type", T.in, ["typeA","typeB"])` works fine but I cant get it to work with gremlin-java driver.

The signature for has() is,
`GremlinFluentPipeline<S,? extends com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Element> has(String key,                                                     Tokens.T compareToken, Object value)`

Parameters:
key - the property key to check
compareToken - the comparison to use
value - the object to filter on

But I can not figure out how I have to pass the value in for it to be accepted.
gremlin-java 2.6.0  ([docs](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/gremlin/2.6.0/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/java/GremlinFluentPipeline.html#has(java.lang.String,%20com.tinkerpop.gremlin.Tokens.T,%20java.lang.Object)))
Scala 2.11.1
Titan 0.5.2

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about Scala, but here's a working example in Java:

```
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.tg.TinkerGraph;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.tg.TinkerGraphFactory;
import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.Tokens.*;
import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.GremlinPipeline;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * @author Daniel Kuppitz (daniel at thinkaurelius.com)
 */
public class App {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final TinkerGraph g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph();
        new GremlinPipeline<Vertex, Vertex>(g).V()
                .has("name", T.in, Arrays.asList("marko","josh")).map()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

If you execute the program above, you'll get the following output:

```
{name=marko, age=29}
{name=josh, age=32}
```

And last but not least, these are the dependencies I've used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
    <artifactId>blueprints-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinkerpop.gremlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>gremlin-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, after looking at your code I realized that it was probably expecting a java.util.list and didnt know how to handle Scala's version of a List.  Using Scala's JavaConverters and .asJava seems to have fixed it.  `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` `new GremlinPipeline(g).V().has("type",T.in, List("typeA", "typeB").asJava)`